# Not finding div tag using class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following program to get the news url of the page below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.sessions import Session
import requests
news_url = []
ses = Session()
last24_url = 'https://www.zoomit.ir/archive/?sort=Newest&skip=20&publishPeriod=Last24Hours'
last24_news_page = ses.get(last24_url , headers={'User-Agent':'https://user-agents.net/string/mozilla-5-0-linux-android-12-cph2251-build-sp1a-210812-003-wv-applewebkit-537-36-khtml-like-gecko-version-4-0-chrome-109-0-5414-118-mobile-safari-537-36-instagram-268-0-0-18-72-android-31-12-480dpi-1080x2237-oppo-cp-41eefdaadc265c91b0279e092ef2286df3f1c865'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(last24_news_page.content , 'html.parser')
news = soup.find_all( 'div' , class_="flex__Flex-le1v16-0 eQTmR")
for new in news:
    url = new.find('a' , class_="link__CustomNextLink-sc-1r7l32j-0 iCQspp").get('href')
    news_url.append(url)
```

[target_url](https://www.zoomit.ir/archive/?sort=Newest&skip=20&publishPeriod=Last24Hours)

[image: site incpect]

I was expecting to get the news url but my list is empty and doesn't find any div tags with this class even though it exists

Comment: The string "eQTmR" does not occur on that page.  It's possible the class names are generated at runtime and change each time.  You might have to fetch all of the `flex__Flex-le1v16-0` divs and use some other criteria to find the interesting parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the news from an API endpoint.

Here's how to do it:

```py
import json
import time

import requests

api_url = "https://api2.zoomit.ir/editorial/api/articles/browse?PageNumber=1&PageSize=50&PublishDate=Last24Hours&Sort=Newest"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.200",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

payload = {
    "PageNumber": 1,
    "PageSize": 50,
    "PublishDate": "Last24Hours",
    "Sort": "Newest",
}


def wait_a_bit(wait_for: int = 1, message: bool = False) -> None:
    if message:
        print(f"Waiting for {wait_for} seconds...")
    time.sleep(wait_for)


def get_news():
    with requests.Session() as session:
        while True:
            response = session.get(api_url, headers=headers, json=payload)
            response.raise_for_status()
            news = response.json()
            # This shows only the first news item in the list; remove [0] to see all
            print(json.dumps(news["source"][0], indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
            payload["PageSize"] += 1
            wait_a_bit(wait_for=3, message=True)
            if not news["hasNext"]:
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_news()
```

This should output:

```json
{
    "id": "408410",
    "title": "بزرگ‌ترین سیاره جهان کدام است؟",
    "slug": "space/408410-what-is-biggest-planet-on-universe",
    "lead": "ستاره‌شناس‌ها تاکنون سیاره‌هایی به اندازه‌ی دو برابر مشتری و ده برابر سنگین‌تر از آن را کشف کرده‌اند، اما محدودیتی برای ابعاد سیاره وجود دارد.",
    "subHeadline": "",
    "isFeatured": false,
    "isAdvertisement": false,
    "publishedDate": "2023-08-25T18:15:00Z",
    "readingTime": 3,
    "author": {
        "userId": "dc314fe7-b4dc-4608-a5cd-bb3f088ee8f8",
        "fullName": "سارا ارجمند",
        "avatarId": "6374ffd5807a6958d6650cfd",
        "articlesCount": 0
    },
    "coverImageLink": {
        "id": "64e6691d88796772a8e350b8",
        "fileName": "superjupiter-planet",
        "alt": "سیاره ابرمشتری",
        "preview": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 800
    },
    "linkIsFollow": false,
    "type": "Internal",
    "mainCategoryId": "49",
    "totalDiscussCount": 0,
    "likesCount": 0
}
Waiting for 3 seconds...
```